# How to find duplicates values in a row and then find largest value in another column based on the duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba

I have three columns - ID, Stage, and Revenue.
The ID string can be duplicated two or more times, so the number of duplicate ids is unknown.

There are two criteria, one is solved.

- If Stage = 5 then Accept is to be written in the last column.
  If not 5 then Reject is to be written.
- Find each duplicate ID and find the highest revenue value for that duplicate ID.
  If it is the highest then mark Accept.
  The lower values will already have reject beside them due to the way I set up the first criteria.

```vb
Sub FindandAssignValue()

    'This will check to see if Stage is a 5 if yes it will Accept if not it 
    'will say Remove -  this works properly

    For currentRow = 2 To LastRow
        
        'Will tell me the current value in the leadstage column
        currentValue = Range("I" & currentRow).Value
        
        If currentValue = "5" Then
            Range("N" & currentRow).Value = "Accept"
        Else
            Range("N" & currentRow).Value = "Remove"
        End If
       
    Next currentRow
    
    currentValue = Range("A" & currentRow).Value   

    Dim MyArray(1 To lr, 1 To lc) As Variant
    'fill up the rows
    
    For r = 1 To lr
        For c = 1 To lc     'fill the columns up
            MyArray(r, c) = Cells(r + 1, c).Value
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

[image: excel sheet]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you format your question a little better?  Newlines are helpful to help people read, and code should be in `codeblocks`.  See our [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) guide!

Comment: Can you give some sample data, and your desired output from that sample? Also, it seems setting "Accept" or "Reject"/"Remove" is already handled in your script - why is it in your question?

Comment: I have add a link below that says excel sheet which shows a sample of what I would like it to look like.  There are two criteria that I need to follow the first accept and reject is for the stage value = 5 the second accept is for the highest revenue for the duplicate id's.  There is probably a better or cleaner way to do this with a 3d array?

Comment: If this was my project and there was a chance that more questions will be asked about the data, then I would use conditional formatting, filters, and formulas to find, filter, and display the results.  On the other hand, if I only cared about the result or if speed was a concern, then I'd create an array of duplicates, quick sort by amount, then loop through it from the top down pulling the first occurrence of each number.  Probably not the fastest or most efficient but certainly fast enough and easy to write.

Comment: So the code works well with the exception of one issue.  Where duplicate values exist and the stage is = 5 it needs to only mark that value as accept not the highest value associate with the id. For example if 1234 is the id and the stage is 4 at 8000 and the next value with id 1234 has a stage value = 5 with a value of 3000 then the second with the stage value of 5 is accepted and the other duplicate with stage 4 and 8000 is rejected.  5 trumps all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a necessary reference (`Open VB Editor > Tools > References > Scroll down until you find "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" > Tick it > Click OK`), I think this code should work.

- You will likely need to change the name of `someSheet` to whatever your worksheet is called.
- I've assumed your source data (including headers) begins in cell `A1` and ends at some row for column `C`. You can change this as needed.
- Results will be written to sheet starting from cell `H1`. You can change this as needed.

---

```
Private Sub AcceptOrRejectSomeValues()

    Dim someSheet As Worksheet
    Set someSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet10") ' Change to whatever yours is called.

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = someSheet.Cells(someSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Assert lastRow > 1

    Dim dataIncludingHeaders As Range
    Set dataIncludingHeaders = someSheet.Range("A1", "C" & lastRow)

    Dim inputArray() As Variant
    inputArray = dataIncludingHeaders.Resize(, dataIncludingHeaders.Columns.Count + 1).Value

    Const ID_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 1
    Const STAGE_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 2
    Const REVENUE_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 3
    Const RESULT_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 4

    Dim booleanArray() As Boolean
    ReDim booleanArray(1 To UBound(inputArray))

    Dim idsAndRowIndexes As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set idsAndRowIndexes = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = (LBound(inputArray, 1) + 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
        booleanArray(rowIndex) = (inputArray(rowIndex, STAGE_COLUMN_INDEX) = "5")

        Dim currentKey As String
        currentKey = CStr(inputArray(rowIndex, ID_COLUMN_INDEX))

        If idsAndRowIndexes.Exists(currentKey) Then
            If inputArray(rowIndex, REVENUE_COLUMN_INDEX) > inputArray(idsAndRowIndexes(currentKey), REVENUE_COLUMN_INDEX) Then
                idsAndRowIndexes(currentKey) = rowIndex
            End If
        Else
            idsAndRowIndexes(currentKey) = rowIndex
        End If
    Next rowIndex

    Dim id As Variant
    For Each id In idsAndRowIndexes.Keys
        booleanArray(idsAndRowIndexes(id)) = True
    Next id

    For rowIndex = LBound(inputArray, 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
        If booleanArray(rowIndex) Then
            inputArray(rowIndex, RESULT_COLUMN_INDEX) = "Accept"
        Else
            inputArray(rowIndex, RESULT_COLUMN_INDEX) = "Reject"
        End If
    Next rowIndex

    someSheet.Range("H1").Resize(UBound(inputArray, 1), UBound(inputArray, 2)).Value = inputArray

End Sub
```